# Referring hardwired information in LaTeX / XeLaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing

In LaTeX, if we hardwire information like theorem numbers, lemma numbers etc., and if we enclose such numbers in a macro then is it possible to 
refer that number. For example,

```
Theorem \thnum{3.4}\label{thm3.4} ....theorem text goes here
```

Inside of text somewhere else if we refer `\ref{thm3.4}`.

Such situations arise when an article does not have any order in numbering scheme.

Comment: The main purpose of the label-ref system is that the label is independent from the number that will eventually be assigned to the object you want to refer to. Tying the label to the actual number defies this purpose and you'll get in big trouble as soon as you add a theorem in between two existing ones, because you will need to chase across the document and manually fix the numbering of the references. Can you clarify what you mean by not having any order in the numbering scheme?

Answer (score 1):

The main macro involved in storing a reference under the default cross-referencing scheme is `\@currentlabel`. So, we define `\thnum` to print the number provided, but also update `\@currentlabel`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thnum}[1]{#1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is some regular text. We are interested in Theorem~\ref{thm3.4}:

\noindent
{\bfseries Theorem \thnum{3.4}\label{thm3.4}} \ldots theorem text goes here

\end{document}
```

If you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), the following definition of `\thnum` should suffice:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thnum}[1]{\phantomsection #1\renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#1}}
\makeatother
```